# Who is responsible for providing ATC in a TMA?

Tags: air-traffic-control

I know that `TWR`, `APP`, and `ACC` control **ATZ**, **CTR**, and **en-route**; but I'm not sure about the control service which is responsible for monitoring `TMA` (`APP` or `ACC`?!).

Could you please clear the case (preferably by a European reference)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

Air traffic control service in a TMA can be provided by either an air traffic control tower (TWR), an approach control unit (APP), or an area control unit (ACC) - or any combination of those.

A TMA is *typically* considered to be APP airspace, but there is no rule preventing a TWR or ACC from covering a TMA, and there are many examples of this happening throughout the world.

The typical division, if you need a simple answer, is:

- TWR provides service in a control zone (CTR)
- APP provides service in a TMA
- ACC provides service in a control area (CTA)

Comment: Sorry for my confusion. You have eliminated `ATZ` and `en-route` in your classification. What did happen to `ATZ` (have you considered it equivalent to `CTR`?), and do you mean that `CTA` is the same as `en-route`?

Comment: ATZ is a UK thing, it is not used in the rest of the world. En-route is not an airspace, it is a phase of flight.